# Telerik grid does not display data

Tags: c#, telerik

Never used telerik controls before but I am using another page as an example.

I retrieve a collection of objects from the database, set the grid.DataSource to that collection, I have verified that the collection contains items, but nothing is displayed.

Here is the grid definition.

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="HelpRequestsGrid" OnNeedDataSource="HelpRequestsGrid_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" ShowHeader="true">
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" ClientDataKeyNames="Id" DataKeyNames="Id" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" 
        ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" Name="Master" NoMasterRecordsText="No help requests found.">
        <NoRecordsTemplate>
            No help requests found.
        </NoRecordsTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id" HeaderText="Help Request ID"
                HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Title" SortExpression="Title" HeaderText="Title" 
                HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Message" SortExpression="Message" HeaderText="Message" 
                HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DeviceName" SortExpression="DeviceName" HeaderText="Device Name" 
                HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CreateDate" SortExpression="CreateDate" HeaderText="Created Date" 
                HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And here is where I populate the datasource.

```
    protected void HelpRequestsGrid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CompanyID > 0 && EventID > 0)
        {
            HelpRequestsGrid.DataSource = Service.GetHelpRequests(EventID, CompanyID);
        }
    }
```

No data is displayed but after the Datasource = line I can confirm that it contains items. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the type of result from `Service.GetHelpRequests`?

Comment: What was the result with `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`

Comment: Service.GetHelpRequests return IEnumberable<HelpRequest>. AutoGenerateColumns yields the same result

Comment: So you have" No help requests found." displayed?

Comment: No, for this company and event there should be 6 items displayed, after I set the ds and step through it shows the DS has 6 items, but this is not displayed in the UI

Comment: my question was about what is displayed: the grid , the header, the no data message? Because i copied your grid to a new telerik project. created a sample datatable, and everything is ok.

Comment: put `var foo = Service.GetHelpRequests(EventID, CompanyID);`
Add a breakpoint and check if your column name are correct if your value are null or white space. As you do not describe what 'not displayed' means, if row are displayed but no information, it must be a nameing or null issue.

Comment: Nothing is displayed - this grid is in a "tab" and when I click into the tab no data is displayed, no column names are displayed, no column headers are displayed.